# How to create a preloader for audio,video,css,images in HTML 5?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, preloader

How to implement a preloader functionality in HTML 5 for audio, video, css and images files.

Please let us know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it utillizes all the preloader functions that i see you need https://github.com/pazguille/aload

And for css i'd recommend https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS